# unable to use imported javac library files

Tags: javacv

i have installed opencv-2.4.10 and javacv according to https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv link. 
I am unable to use various commands from the tutorials or resources from the internet. I am confused that if this error is due to version problem ( opencv-3.0.0) or i haven't imported the .jar files properly.
Like the code below

```
frame = converterToMat.convert(processedMat);
```

i cannot use "convertToMat" and other commands like cvCvtColor etc. 
i use ctrl+shift+o for importing, how to we import the entire library before even using it?? i use eclipse IDE.
please help

Comment: Have you copied the file manually of through maven. Also check in build path of your project if the jar is included or not.

Comment: First i was installing opencv-3.0.0 from the link [http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html#linux-installation] , i got stuck in cmake process downloading ippicv. So i started installing opencv-2.4.10.. Then followed link (https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv), which was successfull ie. gave me java-bin files i guess having .jar files. Yes, the build path has all the .jar files that is provided from the github source. I am confused that if the opencv installation is vital to run javacv in eclipse?? the eclipse doesn't provide me auto-complete hints.